# Flutter - how to fetch data correctly with ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want to fetch data about weather stats for entire app once after app is runned.

My `ChangeNotifier`:

```dart
class WeatherStatsNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  WeatherService weatherService;
  Future<WeatherStats> _stats;

  WeatherStatsNotifier({this.weatherService});

  Future<WeatherStats> get stats => _stats;

  void refreshStats() {
    _stats = weatherService.fetchWeatherStats();
    notifyListeners(); // it works when I remove this line
  }
}
```

My main file:

```dart
final WeatherService weatherService = new WeatherService();

void main() => runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => WeatherStatsNotifier(weatherService: weatherService),
    child: App()));

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    Provider.of<WeatherStatsNotifier>(context, listen: false).refreshStats();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  //... build method
}
```

and somewhere deeper:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<WeatherStatsNotifier>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return FutureBuilder<WeatherStats>(
          future: value.stats,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return _buildForSnapshot(snapshot);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Finally I get an error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building ChangeNotifierProvider<WeatherStatsNotifier>(message: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4195 pos 12: '!_dirty': is not true.\nSee also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors, dirty, renderObject: RenderErrorBox#c84e8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE DETACHED):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4195 pos 12: '!_dirty': is not true.
```

How to do it in correct way? Am I able to use `context` inside `initState` or `didChangeDependencies` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dependencies change, that is WeatherStatsNotifier, `didChangeDependencies` is called. Widget is already considered dirty and build is in progress (there can be multiple listeners).

However your `refreshStats` is notifing listeners **synchronously** which would mean that listeners should be build again, but they are already building. That could lead to inconsistency in the frame so that's why it is an error. That's also why removing this `notifyListeners();` is "fixing" the problem.

The way to fix it is to execute the change async either by `addPostFrameCallback` or `Future.microtask`.

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    Future.microtask(() {
      Provider.of<WeatherStatsNotifier>(context, listen: false).refreshStats();
    });

  }
```

Note that if you have multiple dependencies you probably should check if  instances have changed in `didChangeDependencies`.

Comment: And when exactly `didChangeDependencies` is called? What is difference between `didChangeDependencies` and `didWidgetUpdate` ?
What do "dependencies of state" exactly mean?

Comment: State has a BuildContext and by this context it can subscribe to other elements and Provider is a nice abstraction over this mechanism. See: [dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html). This is called dependency.

Comment: Ok, so please correct me if I don't understand it correctly:
`didChangeDependencies` is called when widget connected with state is changed? 
It happens when something is changed in ChangeNotifier or for example we use `Theme.of` and we change screen orientation?

Comment: When widget is changed didWidgetUpdate is called. When dependency is changed didChangeDependencies is called. `Theme.of` can be a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best practice how to fetch data using value notifier

1. Define the value notifier with the **type data**

```
ex:
class _AppState extends State<App> {
ValueNotifier<String> _weatherStatsNotifier;
```

2. Add to init state for default value (To handle null value) and yes you can use context too if needed

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_weatherStatsNotifier = ValueNotifier(emtpyString);
```

3. Then, Change the value if the data already fetch

```
_weatherStatsNotifier.value = weatherService;
```

or in my case I'm usually using the value notifier from listen state

```
_weatherBloc.listen(
        (state) {
          if (state is weatherLoadedState) {
            _weatherStatsNotifier.value = state.weather;
          }
        },
      );
```

4.Use the data as the return of the data ex String

```
ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
valueListenable: _weatherStatsNotifier,
builder: (context, value, _) => NextScreen(
                                Weather: value,
                                ),
                              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider wrapping your method inside `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` so the method gets called in the next frame and not just when the widget is being rebuilt

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    Provider.of<WeatherStatsNotifier>(context, listen: false).refreshStats();
}
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }


    });
```